# Javascript - Collection of objects with parent properties in common

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, parent, children

I'd like to create a collection of objects that works like an array. Some time ago, I made [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067412/javascript-performing-actions-on-array-elements-on-creation) and I came up with the following solution with the help of the people that helped me:

```
Newobj.Collection = function(){
    Array.apply(this);

    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++){
            this.push(arguments[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return this
}

Newobj.Collection.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Newobj.Collection.prototype.push = function(o){
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, new Newobj.Element(o));
}
```

However, this leaves the children unconnected from the parent. For example, imagine this collection has a `render()` function, which makes its children to print some HTML onto the page. Well, I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
Newobj.Collection.html_container = '#cont';

Newobj.Collection.render = function(){
    $.each(this, function(i, el){
        el.render()
    })
}

Newobj.Element.render = function(){
    $(parent.html_container).html('.......')
}
```

It should be able to set different collections in one page, so make a global `container` for all the `Newobj.Collection`s is not a solution. This is an example, and I need this for more complex processes than just a `render()` function.

Anyone has an idea how can I make an array to be able to access a parent class which it is part of?

*If the solution could be `JSON.stringify`ed and be seen as an array on the server side, it would be great too, though it's not the main problem for this question. Right now, if I set a property to the array, it is seen as an object with `size > 0` on the server side.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create reference to collection in element:

```
Newobj.Collection.prototype.push = function(o){
  Array.prototype.push.call(this, new Newobj.Element(o,this));
}

//element constructor gets as second paramater instance of collection
Newobj.Element=function(o,collection){

  //this.parent in every element is collection reference
  this.parent=collection;
}


Newobj.Element.prototype.render = function(){
   $(this.parent.html_container).html('.......')
}
```

or no reference in Element option:

```
Newobj.Collection.render = function(){

  var parent=this;

  $.each(this, function(i, el){
    el.render(parent.html_container)
  })
}

Newobj.Element.render = function(html_container){
  $(html_container).html('.......')
}
```

But this version need to have methods parameters.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. I'll test it and when I see if it works (that it should, as I read it) I mark your answer as the correct one! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've come up with a *performance* possible problem. If I put the *collection* as a parameter, what will happen to the element number 100 when I get there? Will it have a property called *parent* in which there are 99 other elements already? and the 99th, will have a *parent* property with an array with 98 elements, and so on?

Comment: This paramater is object reference so it will be no 100 objects but one object and 100 references, so it will be no performance problems.

Comment: As it is an object (or it should), it is passed by reference, but I don't know if this will still affect performance on operations such as `JSON.stringify()`, where it will encode the whole parent array. EDIT (we wrote at he same time): ok. I will check! Thank you!

Comment: I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` because of the reference... Do you know any way I can do it without having to implement my own serialisation method?

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark the answer as correct because I think these are the most correct methods to use! I will think wether to use one or another. Thank you again for your help!